# Detect image colour from touch location

Tags: swift, xcode, drawing, uitouch

I am trying to build a simple drawing app that can act as a virtual guest book. Ive managed to put something simple together which allows a user to draw onto a UIImage however I cannot figure out a way to erase a drawing somebody creates without using the eraser function that I create as white. I would like to set an image however I need to figure out a way that the eraser can detect the correct colour to use based on where the users finger will be when erasing to match the image.

My eraser currently updates a set of variables (red, green, blue) the erasers function is @IBAction func eraser

I've tried a few functions that I've came across which are outdated

```
//
//  SecondViewController.swift
//  Guest Book
//
//  Created by Stephen Clifford on 25/07/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 Stephen Clifford. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var toolicon: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!


var lastPoint = CGPoint.zero
var swiped = false
var red:CGFloat = 0.00
var green:CGFloat = 0.00
var blue:CGFloat = 0.00
var alpha:CGFloat = 1
var lw:CGFloat = 2.5
var tool:UIImageView!
var isDrawing = true
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tool = UIImageView()
    tool.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.size.width, y: self.view.bounds.height, width: 75, height: 75)
    tool.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pen")
    self.view.addSubview(tool)
}

@IBAction func eraser(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if (isDrawing) {
        (red,green,blue) = (1,1,1)
        tool.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "eraser")
        toolicon.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pen"), for: .normal)
        (lw) = (50)


    } else {
        (red,green,blue) = (0,0,0)
        tool.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pen")
        toolicon.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "eraser"), for: .normal)
        (lw) = (2.5)
    }

    isDrawing = !isDrawing
}

func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}

@IBAction func save(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let image = imageView.image {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
        self.imageView.image = nil

        // the alert view
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Thank you, your guestbook entry has been saved. Redirecting you the home page", preferredStyle: .alert)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        // change to desired number of seconds (in this case 5 seconds)
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2.5
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when){
            // your code with delay
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        delay(3.0) {
            // do stuff
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "savetocam", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
@IBAction func lineSize(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if sender.tag == 8 {
        (lw) = (1)
    } else if sender.tag == 9 {
        (lw) = (2.5)
    } else if sender.tag == 10 {
        (lw) = (5)
    }
}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    swiped = false
    if let touch = touches.first  {
        lastPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
    }
}

@IBAction func colorsPicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if sender.tag == 0 {
        (red,green,blue) = (0,0,0)
    } else if sender.tag == 1 {
        (red,green,blue) = (0.25,0.00,0.39)
    } else if sender.tag == 2 {
        (red,green,blue) = (0.65,0.62,0.75)
    } else if sender.tag == 3 {
        (red,green,blue) = (1.00,0.00,0.00)
    } else if sender.tag == 4 {
        (red,green,blue) = (0.49,0.77,0.46)
    } else if sender.tag == 5 {
        (red,green,blue) = (0.0,0.68,0.94)
    } else if sender.tag == 6 {
        (red,green,blue) = (0.96,0.56,0.34)
    } else if sender.tag == 7 {
        (red,green,blue) = (1.00,0.95,0.00)
    }
}



@IBAction func reset(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.imageView.image = nil
}


func drawLines(fromPoint:CGPoint,toPoint:CGPoint) {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    imageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    context?.move(to:CGPoint(x: fromPoint.x, y: fromPoint.y))
    context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: toPoint.x, y: toPoint.y))

    context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
    context?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
    context?.setLineWidth(lw)
    context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha).cgColor)

    context?.strokePath()

    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    swiped = true
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
        drawLines(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)

        lastPoint = currentPoint
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if !swiped {
        drawLines(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: lastPoint)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to keep the original image intact and do the drawing (and erasing) on another view shown over the image?

Comment: I have thought about doing that, but it would still show the eraser as white, also another function saves the image to the camera roll